# How to reconfigure or reset keyboard layout switching?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

There seem to be many [problems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs?field.tag=keyboard-layout-switching-hotkeys) with keyboard layout switching in Ubuntu.

For me (Ubuntu with Gnome Shell), it used to work until version 13.10, maybe 14.04. Currently I am on 15.04.

Even then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> would work but for some reason layout started to switch also using <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd> which is greatly annoying because I tend to press this combination inadvertently when typing.

In Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing, "Modifiers-only switch to next source" is set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. All the other options there are unset.

Where else can you set the layout switching shortcuts?

In some questions and answers I see people referring to the "Text Entry" app - I don't see it anywhere, I guess it was changed in later versions?

Also, I don't know if this is related, in "Input Method Configuration", I see the following:

```
Active configuration: ibus (normally missing)
Number of valid choices: 2 (normally 1)
Available input methods: ibus xim
Unless you really need them all, please make sure to install only one input method tool.
```

[image: Input Method Configuration window screenshot]

Another problem is that the switching layouts doesn't work well. Sometimes I have to switch three times before it actually switches. Also the indicator shows the wrong language. I usually have two layouts: en and cs. Sometimes the indicator shows en while the layout is cs, or even the other way around I guess. It's all just a mess.

Is there a way to reconfigure/reset the layout switching, a way to start from scratch?

Is there some official Ubuntu guide? Does it work better in other distros? Maybe there's a relevant guide for ArchLinux?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that setting was for old releases (if i remember <13.10) which expect only one input method (`xim`). It is still used for Xubuntu & Lubuntu. For Ubuntu/Gubuntu, You are right the new setting is:

Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Typing

I see you are using `ibus` as default input method. So some shortcuts may override by `ibus` because it has its own settings and can filter input.

If you have to use `ibus` for CTL language input, check it configuration `ibus-setup`, probably these below options are related, however check all settings:

- Advanced tab → *Use system keyboard layout*
- General tab → *Net input method* shortcut

Also check that all you GUI kits (GTK, QT ..) use same input method:

```
env | grep -i im
```

If you don't really need it disable `ibus` (Also you may disable it just to test, if the issue originates from it)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to details in [Debian wiki Keyboard topic](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard), I often use the following command to reset `compose:ralt` layout option when switching between keyboards layout:

```
sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
```